# Python Simulation Inconsistency

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, simulator

I have made a simulator using Python for a game called Final Fantasy XII. The purpose of this simulator is to see how much "gil" (in-game currency) you can get from one particular enemy.

This should output around 23000 from our experiance, but what happens with this is, ***it outputs 24000 usually, but sometimes 29000.*** Considering it takes 1000 samples, it is impossible for that to be coincident. I think this code has problems with random generator, but I have no idea.

Are there reasons python simulator sometimes goes wrong?

```
import random

# defining variables, dictionaries and functions here

for t in range (1, test + 1):
    for n in range (1, dustia + 1):

        c = c + 1 # first, increase the chain counter

        r = random.random()
        # deciding a thing using "if r < [probability]" here

        # ....

        # apparently this part caused the problem
        r = random.random()
        if m == 1 and r < 0.4:
            m = 0
        elif m == 0 and r < 0.05:
            m = 1


        r1 = random.random() # RNG for book
        r2 = random.random() # RNG for staff
        rr1 = random.random() # amount of books
        rr2 = random.random() # amount of staff
        # deciding another thing using r < [probability] here

#summing up samples and calculating average here
```

Comment: SO is not a debugging service for you to dump all your code hoping someone will do the work for you. [mcve]

Comment: Im not here for a debugging, but just want to know if there is some inconsistency in python simulation

Comment: Have you tried plotting out a histogram of the results?

Comment: i just realised i didnt reset some variables in for loop. im sorry for hasty posting